# How to skip a number in loop JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (!i == 5)
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
} 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

In the code above I want to loop from 0 to 10 but i want to skip number 5. I want to show from 0 to 4, skip 5, then show from 6 to 10. The code above does not work.

Comment: `if( i != 5`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `continue`

```js
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i == 5) continue;
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
} 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Another way is to wrap the code inside an `if` statement inside `for` block

```js
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i !== 5){
    text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  }
} 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

`if (!i == 5)` should be `if (i !== 5)`

Answer (score 1):

If you add `!(i == 5)` then the solution will work.

```js
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (!(i == 5))
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
} 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Or either shorter way with ES6 which I prefer:

```js
const reduce = (a, c, i) => i === 5 ? a : a.concat(`The number is ${c}<br>`);
const text = Array.from(Array(10).keys()).reduce(reduce, '');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a generator that yields indices that are not in its "skips" list.

```js
const rangeWithSkip = function*(start, end, skips) {
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
    if (skips.includes(i)) continue;
    yield i;
  }
}

let textArr = [];
for (let i of rangeWithSkip(0, 10, [3, 5, 8])) {
  textArr.push(`The number is ${i}`);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textArr.join('<br />');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```